# How do I get the entirety of an uncompressed gzip file using Zlib?

Tags: ruby, gzip, zlib

I am trying to uncompress a 823,000 line file, but I'm only receiving 26,000 lines of the file. I'm new to I/O and for some reason, not grasping why this is the case. Here is my code:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.open( file_path ) do |gz|
    puts gz.readlines.count
  end
```

Any direction would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have another file that is 52,000 lines and it returns just over 700 lines when I try it. These are server log files, if that makes  a difference.

Comment: The text editor you're viewing the file with might have word wrap on, giving the illusion of more lines?

Comment: It's Sublime. Word wrap is on but it's an accurate line number.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you try posting a complete procedure for reproducing this problem?  Here is a shell session from Ubuntu with Ruby 2.2.0 where I tried and failed to reproduce your problem:  https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/98c4ffd987019b9fc1ed

Comment: Reduce your sample file to 10 lines. Compress it using `gzip`. Try opening it and see how many lines you get.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I managed to fix this.
It turns out the server log file I was using had about 29 streams of data in it. Zlib::GzipReader only read the first one. In order to fix it, I had to loop through until all 29 streams had been read:

```
File.open(  file_path ) do |file|
    zio = file
    loop do
      io = Zlib::GzipReader.new( zio )
      uncompressed += io.read
      unused = io.unused # where I'm writing my file
      break if unused.nil?
      zio.pos -= unused.length
    end
  end
```